# What does it mean that "Sample mean is independent of the sample variance when the distribution is normal"?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean

I am having hard time understanding this statement. First of all, how can they be independent as we use sample mean to calculate the sample variance; squared distances from the mean. This is why I am having hard time understanding this statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the variance so that it doesn't explicitly depend on the mean, which may be helpful.

Any individual observation $X_i$ is an unbiased estimator of the mean, and the sample average $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i$ is a good estimator

For any pair of observatios $X_i$, $X_j$, an unbiased estimator of the variance is $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i\neq j} (X_i-X_j)^2$

Suppose you have two observations.  The independence claim is that $X_i+X_j$ is independent of $(X_i-X_j)^2$.  That's not obviously untrue. In particular, $X_i+X_j$ is uncorrelated with $X_i-X_j$, which is a weaker property related to independence.

For bivariate Normal variables in particular, if $X_i+X_j$ is *uncorrelated* with $X_i-X_j$ then they are actually *independent*, and so the mean and variance are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an educational handout](https://jekyll.math.byuh.edu/courses/m321/handouts/mean_var_indep.pdf) that demonstrates the well-known result in statistics of the independence of sample mean and variance for the Normal distribution.

The work is readable, complete and the topic is answered, albeit, in the course of some five pages.

I hope this helps.